# yii2: how to render a view in mail

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer

I am able to send mail using swiftmailer extension. I am also able to include the view file from @app/mail folder.

Now I am wondering how I can include the data for my model views for example say I have a Model City.php and  related view as view.php or index.php(grid-view) how can I include the data rendered in view.php(single record) or table data in index.php in mail body.

In short I want to include the default data rendered in yii2 in views or index in mail body.

Hi, I have seen this example like - `Yii::$app->mailer->compose('viewName', ['variable' => $variable])`

another example - `Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contact/html', ['contactForm' => $form])`

I have tried like this without much success:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('medicine-request-entry/html',['medicine_request_entry'=>$form])
```

but I am getting the error undefined variable form. `medicie_request_entry` is the folder in views folder.(not in @app/views)

but couldn't get it. Say my view name in /mail/ subfolder is say report.php and I have a folder in my views subfoler /city/ and in city folder there is view.php and index.php how I can specify this in the parameter  in the example code.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I found the solution and putting the answer for anyone having the same difficulty

I modified the code in my controller like:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/views/medicine-request-entry/view',['model'=>$model])
```

But I still didn't get, how to use layout given in `@app/mail` or to send the mail as html.

Thanks.

Comment: For use layouts should add 'viewPath' => '@common/mail' to the config in section 'components'->'mailer' and in folder common/mail/layouts make two files html.php and text.php

Comment: That helped me a lot, thank you very much @AndreyYaremenko and Pawan

Answer (score 0):

```
\Yii::$app->mailer->htmlLayout = "@app/mail/layouts/html";

$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/welcome');

var_dump($message);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.